# FOSJsRoutingBundle: undefined protocol and domain in routing output

Tags: javascript, symfony, url-routing

I use FOSJsRoutingBundle to bring my routes to JavaScript. My controller annotation:

```
/* 
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Route("/search/{searchterm}", name="_api_player_search", options={"expose"=true})
 */
```

My JavaScript:

```
console.log(Routing.generate('_api_player_search', {searchterm: 'aaron', limit: 5}, true));
```

The output in firebug console:

```
undefined://undefinedundefined/api/player/search/aaron?limit=5
```

Testing on a local xampp server, Symfony v 2.4.2, FOSJsRoutingBundle in is actual version from 18. Feb 2014.

You see the problem? What have i done wrong?

Comment: Did you add the configuration in your `app/config/routing.yml`?

Comment: yeah like
`fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"`

Comment: Have you include in your layout?

`<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename your route name to somthing like

```
/* 
 * @Route("/search/{searchterm}", 
   name="apiPlayerSearch",
   options={"expose"=true},
   methods={"GET"}
   )
 */
```

Then run

```
php app/console fos:js-routing:dump
```

This could work as i had a similar problem.